# using background process take large db back up in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, background, parallel-processing, backup

What I basically want to do is have my php web application click on button ( excel report generator) that may take a few  minute  and immediately return control to the page process terminate.

So here's the workflow:

User clicks 'generate Report' button
ajax call made to '../city/generate-report' and returns immediately

process is started and runs until completion while the user can then go about his business
User can return to report page and see progress: "Report 50% complete"
What's the best way to accomplish this? Brief answers are fine. I don't want code written for me, just some guidance. I looked at shell_exec but I'm not sure exactly if that is the best way or if it is, how to use it to process functions within a web app. (cakephp 2.0 framework if that makes any difference). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- How often do you think the backup script will run?
- It should not be possible to run multiple instances in the same time,
  correct? Would setting this up a cron work? (nightly, or two times a
  day)
- The backup script should be a [Shell script](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html).

The `generate-report` action would somehow trigger that script. Either execute command on the server, or change a flag in the database that a cron can pick up.

The shell script would only allow one instance and you will have a database table with the status of the backup (percentage and other details).

So the flow will be:

- access `generate-report`: no instance is running, to the backup shell starts
- the shell script constantly updates the percentage completed field in the table
- the `generate-report` is accessed every few seconds and reads the percentage (because the shell is already running)